# Regex for url ending with a slash

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex for preg_replace for replacing urls ending with a slash (/). But it also replaces urls with .jpg at the end. For urls it works fine, but it should not replace the .jpg urls. Can someone help me please?

```
protected function _rewriteUrls($sContent)
{
        $target      = $this->getConfig()->getConfigParam('sShopURL').$this->_getToxidLangSeoSnippet().'/';
        $source    = str_replace('.','\.',$this->_getToxidLangSource());
        $actual    = '%href="'.$source.'(?=.*?.html)%';
        $should    = 'href="'.$target;
        return preg_replace($actual, $should, $sContent);
}
```

This code is from an OXID module called TOXID to combine OXID with another system like wordpress. $sContent should contain any HTML from a Wordpress blog. So this basically rewrites URLs so that it looks like I am navigating inside the OXID shop. As you can see, originally it has got .html in its Regex, but this is useless if you have different URL patterns. So I changed it to a slash (/). Unfortunately it also changes URLs for .jpg.

Here is sample data for sContent:
http://pastebin.com/nTXAAhWq

Comment: Can you post what `$sContent` looks like?

Comment: Yes, it would help to see some samples of what you're trying to match. Also what results you're expecting for those samples. I *think* what you want would be accomplished with a non-greedy quantifier, but it's not entirely clear.

Comment: I added more information about the function.

Comment: @tutorial-portal.com We still don't know what the string looks like - can you `var_dump($sContent)` ? Is it just `href="ds/f/sdf` or `asdf .d..href="/dsf/sadf/" ..df.s `

Comment: I suspect you need to change this to `$actual = '%href="'.$source.'(?=[^"]*?.html)%'`. I suspect the lookforward assertion is looking past the tag and into a future tag to pick up the next '.html'.

Comment: Sorry, I added now sample data for sContent.

Comment: @tutorial-portal Please post actual *examples*, not verbal descriptions, as well as what you'd like the results to look like (again, actually show us, don't describe them). What you added requires one to be familiar with Wordpress blogs and OXID, so you're ***severely*** narrowing the pool of potential respondents. Give us examples, and anyone who knows regex can help.

Comment: I see what you posted, but please take the guesswork and inference out of the exercise by giving examples, i.e. provide a URL that you want the regex to match, followed by how you want it to look after the replace, and provide a URL that you don't want to match, with an explanation of what about it should violate the regex's conditions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$actual    = '%href="'.$source.'(?=.*?/)"%'; //if $sContent = '.. href="my/path/" ...'
$should    = 'href="'.$target.'"';
```

The `$` specifies the end of the line, useful if `$sContent` ends before the `href` attribute's closing speech marks

```
$actual    = '%href="'.$source.'(?=.*?/)$%'; //if $sContent = 'href="my/path/'
```

Comment: How is that going to work, if you're trying to match a **%** after the end of the string?

Comment: @AdiInbar `%` is the delimeter (instead of standard `/` so `\/` isn't required)

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Oh, right, *duh*! I've been spending too much time with PowerShell lately, where the quotes are the delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Modified based on the content you linked to:

```
$actual = '%href="'.$source.'(?=.*?/")%';
```

Comment: This doesn't work... Yes my regular expression should get all URLS like www.test.com/mypage/ and no files like www.test.com/picture.jpg. But it get's both.

Comment: @tutorial-portal.com Well, what does **$source** look like?

Comment: I edited the answer after looking at the content you linked to, but since you still haven't posted examples of what you want to match and what you want the results of the replace to look like, I'm still just guessing at what you want. I can only infer that from the regex itself, so if there are other mistakes in it, then it's misleading me. Are you trying to replace instances of **$source** in URL's with **$target**, but *only if* the URL ends with a slash? If so, the modification you made to **$actual** doesn't make sense - why did the slash morph into `.html`?

Comment: I added now example data. The slash morphed into .html because I posted now the absolute original code. My modification on it was to change .html into a slash.

Comment: I don't see the examples. Your question was last edited half an hour ago.